# How to share common utility files/functions , common css or design systems in module federation using react?

Tags: reactjs, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am new to module federation , and I am trying to federate my monolith project into multiple Micro frontends but I have some common utility functions , global css that are being used across the application . I have searched online but did not get any result .
I know we have single-spa where we can use utility module .
[global css in single-spa](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-css/#webpack-css-resources)
And also in angular we have with module federation we have  :
[angular module federation](https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/blob/main/libs/mf/README.md)

But I specifically need common utility functions and global css or design systems that can be shared across the MFEs only using **module federation** with **react** without using any other third party library

I can think of two possibilities

1. Using single-spa with module federation and
2. Create a common MFE which any MFE can use .

But not sure if this would be the most optimised way also kindly let me if any other ways are there.